# @font-face not displaying on Internet Explorer its working in Google chrome

Tags: css, font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
    src: url('Entypo-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Entypo-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Entypo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Entypo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Entypo-webfont.svg#EntypoRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

This is working in Google Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. It is working locally in IE but not working when I publish.

Comment: Why you add `c#` tag ? It looks irrelevant.

Comment: Sure the eot file is served from IIS?

Comment: @ Linus Caldwell Yes, Because its working in Crome

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think Chrome uses the eot. Eot is just used by the dirty ones from Redmond.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Irish has made an excellent article on this subject:
[Bulletproof font-face implementation](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

`@font-face {

    font-family: 'EntypoRegular';

    src: url('Entypo-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), url('Entypo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),

    url('Entypo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');

}`

Comment: do you have the correct settings for mime types on the server?